# "[Variable] was used before it was defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I have several of these errors and I am not sure how to "properly" solve it, the thing is that I have many javascript files (Seperated for easier maintainability) and I include plugins et cetera.

So in this example I use shortcut which is from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

This just defines shortcut to

```
shortcut = {.......
```

then when I in my code use it like

```
 shortcut.add("F1", function () { showDialog(); }, { 'type': 'keydown', 'propagate': false, 'target': editor_document });
```

jslint will complain that

> JS Lint: 'shortcut' was used before it was defined.

I also have my own code where I use functions declared in other files, so what is the "right" way to solve this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the variable is defined by another file, you can tell JSLint by providing a comment in the following format:

```
/*global shortcut*/
```

You can do this for a number of variables by comma separating them.  Appending `:` and `true` or `false` (defaults to `false`) will specify whether the variable can be reassigned by the current file:

```
/*global shortcut:false, otherVar:true*/
```

---

You're missing the `var` keyword, which is used to define a variable for the global and function scopes.

```
var shortcut = { }
```

You need to *use `var` for **every** variable defined*, else you'll run into a mass of problems.

It *is* possible to create implicit globals by omitting the `var` keyword, but it's highly frowned upon and not at all recommended.  If you need to create a global variable from an inner scope, you can add the object to `window` or, depending on the context, `this`:

```
function defineShortcut() {
    window.shortcut = {};
    /* or this.shortcut = {}; */
}

defineShortcut();
```

Comment: Be careful of saying "current scope", because it's not the whole story; `let` is for block scope, `var` goes to the function scope.

Comment: No I do not, as stated shortcut is not my code, look at http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js it do not have a var infront of it. And that is not even my question, if I pop a var infront that will not solve my js lint problem, it will still be "used before defined" because its defined in another file.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: `let` is not officially part of the ECMAScript standard yet (ES Harmony has a proposal for it), so you shouldn't really be using it in live code.  However, you do have a point and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mech0z: I'm sorry, I didn't read your question properly.  I've updated my answer with the correct solution.

Comment: I have added window.shortcut when I access it now, but wouldnt this work with all variables? so even if they are not defined in any file jslint will still accept it?

Comment: hmm then it seems like a mini hack as I can get a lot of code to "work" without getting any errors if its not defined :/ I am starting to really not like how loose javascript is..

Answer (score 0):

you must declare a variable shortcut with var keyword before using it, or else it will be a global variable which are considered (and are in fact) evil.

```
var shortcut;

shortcut = { ...
```