# How can I tell jslint that a function is external?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/

if (json.RowKey !== json.NewRowKey) {
   $("#row_" + row).attr('data-rk', json.RowKey);
   updateGridMeta(entity, json.PartitionKey, json.NewRowKey, row, obj.table);
   updateGridTitles();
}
```

lint is reporting that updateGridTitles is used before it is defined. Is there a way to add something to the top of my script to tell it to not report this?

Answer (score 2):

if `updateGridTitles` is defined later you could simply add

```
var updateGridTitles;
```

to the top

Comment: updateGridTitles is defined in another file so I think it's something global. Can I define that in /*global ?

Answer (score 2):

The same way as the other variables you are telling JSLint are global.

Add it to this list:

```
/*global $, jQuery*/
```

Such:

```
/*global $, jQuery, updateGridMeta */
```

Comment: Yes, its a comma separated list.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed tell jslint that a function is global. Have a look at their documentation here:
http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#global
and another question asked here: [JSLint: was used before it was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined)