# JSLint suppress warning on IntellijJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jslint, jshint

I´m using intellij 14 and I just active the JSLint and JSHint, and it´s pretty useful, burt I dont like the code style of declare variables like var a,b,c instead var a; var b; and var c; 
So now all my code is full of warnings saying 'combine this with the previous var statement'.
Can anybody tell me where can I suppress this warning?. I cannot find it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to Tolerate: `many var statements` in your JSLint settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, I thought that option was doing something else. And my last question regarding JDLint. How can I get rid of the warning 'function' was used before it was defined. Regards.

Comment: You can define the function name using the global keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined

Comment: Yes I already have that for all the JQuery libraries, but I was expecting to get rid of the warnings without have to tell which functions. Let´s say I dont mind the order of definition on my js, so if I have var b=function(){ a()}; function a(){} I dont want to take care to define first a before var b