# JSLint throwing error when using console.log()

Tags: javascript, text-editor

The text editor that I am using is [Brackets](http://brackets.io/). I am encountering an error message when I try to use `console.log` in any JS file.

1 - Create/Open an JS file

2 - Type console.log('hello world');

3 - Save the file

**JSLint Problem:**

`error message in JSLint 'console' was used before it was defined.`

Comment: You should find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`devel`](http://jslint.com/help.html#browser) option:

> `true` if browser globals that are useful in development should be predefined, and if debugger statements and TODO comments should be allowed. It adds the same globals as this directive:
>
> ```
> /*global
> alert, confirm, console, prompt
> */
> ```
>
> Be sure to turn this option off before going into production.

So at the top of your script add this line:

```
 /*jslint devel: true */
```

Comment: Thank you , I added `/*jslint devel: true */ ` to the top of my file.